# Viewing sqlite database file using DB browser for SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to save some data in `SQLite` database in an android app.

**Problem**

Data is saved and read without any problem but when I try to view the database file using `DB browser for SQLite`, database file is empty, it has no tables.

I have all three database files

1. `.db`
2. `.db-shm`
3. `.db-wal`

in the same directory but that doesn't makes any difference.

**Question**

How can I view the database file in `DB browser for SQLite`?

Comment: seems that you have open `SQLiteDatabase` - you have to `close()` it

Comment: What program "saved and read without any problems"? Are you sure it's using the same database file?

Comment: @Shawn yes I am sure, its the same database file.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684314/how-do-i-open-a-sqflite-database-file-in-db-browser-for-sqlite